# receive the data of users input text field

Tags: jquery

The MarkUp

```
<div id="tool_wrapper">
Tip: <input class="input_mod" id="tip_tip" type="text"/>
Text: <input class="input_mod" id="text_tip" type="text" />
<input type="submit" class="modbutton" id="sub_tip" />
</div>
```

The jQuery

```
$(function(){
  var a = $('#tip_tip').text();
  var b = $('#text_tip').val();
  var text = $('#text_editor_textarea');
$('#sub_tip').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
     text.val(text.val()+'[mod=' + a + ']' + b + '[/mod]');
  });
});
```

Ok so above jQuery the `var a` `var b` one is `.text();` and the other is `.val()` I know I wanted to state that I have tried both of these then I also tried this

```
$(function(){
  var a = $('#tip_tip').val(function(){
       $(this).text()
});
  var b = $('#text_tip').val(function(){
       $(this).text()
});
  var text = $('#text_editor_textarea');
$('#sub_tip').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
     text.val(text.val()+'[mod=' + a + ']' + b + '[/mod]');
  });
});
```

Which got me farther then the first jQuery though the rendered markup looks like this

`[mod=[object Object]][object Object][/mod]`

Which of course is not what I want. Any suggestions?

Comment: `[object Object]` is the string representation of a JavaScript object, so for some reason `a` and `b` are not what you expect them to be. If you do `console.log(a, b);` within the click-callback, what do you get in your console?

Comment: What's wrong with first jquery snippet?

Comment: of course you would edit it after I asked not to Matt

Comment: @sbmaxx nothing is returned it comes back as `[mod=][/mod]`

Comment: oh and @sbmaxx that is exactly what I said after I tried it about a hundred times LOL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this

```
$(function(){
var text = $('#text_editor_textarea');
$('#sub_tip').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var a = $('#tip_tip').val();
    var b = $('#text_tip').val();
    text.val(text.val()+'[mod=' + a + ']' + b + '[/mod]');
  });
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/h6HFc/).

Comment: ok so I looked at it and why does this work and not the above with .val()? is it because it is out of the .click() function?

Comment: @EasyBB, Yes, because those variables are outside of the click handler and initialized empty and also to get the value of a `text box` you should use `val` instead of `text`.

Comment: yeah that is what I thought, but after trying my first snippet I was heck I'll try .text() lol. But yeah I see now the var a and b where being ran before the .click function ok. Thanks I got it now. I'm trying to accept but I guess theres a time limit before accepting